# Rails: check if the model was really saved in after_save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, callback, after-save

ActiveRecord use to call after_save callback each time save method is called even if the model was not changed and no insert/update query spawned.

This is the default behaviour actually. And that is ok in most cases.

But some of the after_save callbacks are sensitive to the thing that if the model was actually saved or not.

Is there a way to determine if the model was actually saved in the after_save?

I am running the following test code:

```
class Stage < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_save do
    pp changes
  end
end

s = Stage.first
s.name = "q1"
s.save!
```

Comment: not very clear question to me.. can't you just check model.new_record? ?

Comment: after_save? useless... always false.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ActiveRecord use to call after_save
>   callback each time save method is
>   called even if the model was not
>   changed and no insert/update query
>   spawned.

ActiveRecord executes :after_save callbacks each time the record is successfully saved regardless it was changed.

```
# record invalid, after_save not triggered
Record.new.save

# record valid, after_save triggered
r = Record.new(:attr => value)

# record valid and not changed, after_save triggered
r.save
```

What you want to know is if the record is changed, not if the record is saved.
You can easily accomplish this using `record.changed?`

```
class Record

  after_save :do_something_if_changed

  protected

  def do_something_if_changed
    if changed?
      # ...
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: changed? always false after save!

Comment: Did you try? `changed?` status should be reset after the last `after_save` callback is executed.

Comment: I'm testing it with Rails 2.3.5 and it worked for me. Update your question with your example so that I can test it.

Comment: Note: changed? wont be true for 'after_destroy', so take care if the same handler covers both cases.

Comment: changed? always return false as @bogdan said. Because after_save method returns the record before saved I guess. Is there any way to get an updated (saved) object in after_save ?

Answer (score 7):

After a save, check to see if the object saved is a new object

```
a = ModelName.new
a.id = 1
a.save
a.new_record?
#=> false
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else landing here, latest rails 5 has a model method `saved_changes?` and a corresponding method `saved_changes` which shows those changes.

```rb
book = Book.first
book.saved_changes?
=> false

book.title = "new"
book.save

book.saved_changes?
=> true
book.saved_changes
=> {"title" => ["old", "new"]},
```